# Generating Peaks

Tags: plotting

Is there any way to generate peaks in the impulses that I have from plot my data?

```
     vz = {0.6957398098061844`, -13.2280186321222`, -28.783275960960054`, 
  -47.51168915652232`, -71.72150300663026`, -105.26585420224569`, 
 -155.2291672634849`, -236.03906860293932`, -380.9730749375306`, 
 -680.6421880569637`, -1445.8555411505145`, -4054.694963802564`, 
 -9257.734861128327`, -3807.5354790592583`, -1412.9377138175796`, 
-689.1241724030094`, -397.8037535655759`, -254.02293627196087`, 
-172.60367711944596`, -121.66567637351446`, -87.18367644508169`, 
-62.19086432097987`, -42.86440352849152`, -26.901324714599554`, 
-12.762116924014776`, 0.7278924919230576`, 14.629456483772742`, 
30.098680270677903`, 48.63439082121573`, 72.4684451906316`, 
105.30603662507434`, 153.9195969741658`, 232.00702655977454`, 
370.8920239973864`, 654.905674364253`, 1369.1906012714835`, 
3775.6581325880347`, 9355.838010388217`, 4083.1959433782204`, 
1477.4275996016588`, 709.1390955876906`, 405.78878720933324`, 
257.9271928789956`, 174.92896989439507`, 123.34676946454354`, 
88.61145505725548`, 63.5395885907223`, 44.21201936880797`, 
28.278069372971146`, 14.170848017622887`, 0.6957398098061844`};

vx = {107.44772067226873`, 110.17393298474664`, 114.87263226317995`, 
121.95082833276663`, 132.09578202204847`, 146.45539130270237`, 
167.00463581617922`, 197.34470696661745`, 244.62757145450087`, 
324.795303377781`, 478.40515161935235`, 795.222302770521`, 
626.3877303370924`, -224.15181204655542`, -265.01158182092905`, 
-222.42919855092993`, -186.8720255961065`, -161.45433193314165`, 
-143.38036699982834`, -130.41326700429335`, -121.10661327483133`, 
-114.55019154396341`, -110.1756158363907`, -107.63983362928475`, 
-106.76017681062724`, -107.482283069632`, -109.87162093810444`, 
-114.12660496857268`, -120.6183597397515`, -129.9725490323374`, 
-143.22913921430927`, -162.1636276239314`, -189.97798234599276`, 
-232.93393710436249`, -304.6839046787066`, -438.8312067593346`, 
-706.357761870197`, -560.4662641951612`, 266.36951920874816`, 
 284.0971493752178`, 230.80459349499793`, 190.65296657040403`, 
163.04573445573766`, 143.84614438907295`, 130.28439913100178`, 
120.67731212039031`, 114.00013359349369`, 109.62624190387636`, 
107.18317327614017`, 106.47553731918097`, 107.44772067226873`};



  arc[vzz_, vxx_, i_] := ArcTan[vz[[i]], vx[[i]]]
angle = Reap[Do[Sow[arc[vz, vx, i]], {i, Length[vx]}]][[-1, 1]];
sqr[vzz_, vxx_, i_] := Sqrt[vx[[i]]^2 + vz[[i]]^2]
mod = Reap[Do[Sow[sqr[vz, vx, i]], {i, Length[vx]}]][[-1, 1]];
table = Table[{angle[[i]], mod[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[mod]}];
p = ListLinePlot[table, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

I tried to include more points for vx and vz up to 5000, but it still gives the same shape (impulses without peaks).

Comment: Is this what you want `ListLinePlot[Sort@table, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> Full]`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works for the middle peak, but it connected the first peak to the last one.

Comment: That's why I've sorted your `table` first, this way your points would be connected in order.

Comment: Thank you! I saw that.  But is there a way to complete the first peak because I only need the first and the second peaks and I noticed that the part I need to complete the first peak is on the third one.

Comment: Well, that's how your data is constructed, so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: And instead of doing this weird `Sow` and `Reap` stuff, why not just `Table` : `angle = Table[arc[vz, vx, i], {i, Length[vx]}]`

Comment: Thank you for your comments!

Comment: ListPlot[Tooltip[vx]] ,                 vxpeaks = FindPeaks[vx]         ,          ListLinePlot[
 vx, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[vxpeaks]}, PlotRange -> All]